# Bleach Bit - How to Wipe Free Space via Command Line?

Tags: bleachbit

I'm trying to figure out how to run the "wipe free disk space" via the command line on Ubuntu 16.04 with Bleach Bit. It looks like the bleachbit command utility can only wipe specific caches. Does anyone have any ideas on how to do this?

[image: The option I'm referring to in the Bleach Bit GUI]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bleachbit console application has several options:

> ```
> $ bleachbit --help
> Options
> ...
> -l, --list-cleaners   list cleaners
> -c, --clean           run cleaners to delete files and make other permanent
>                       changes
> ...
> -p, --preview         preview files to be deleted and other changes
> ```

so if I call it with

> ```
> $ bleachbit -l | grep free
> ```

I can get

> ```
> system.free_disk_space
> ```

It seems that you should call it with

```
bleachbit -c -p system.free_disk_space # remove -p if you want real action
```

---

Note: if we look into BleachBit's source code - we can see how it calls the above action in [`cb_wipe_free_space` for *Wipe Free Space* label](https://bazaar.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-branches/ubuntu/wily/bleachbit/wily-proposed/view/head:/bleachbit/GUI.py#L552).

Answer (score 2):

The answer from @N0rbert is the best for BleachBit version 2.0 and earlier. Please note it uses the directories configured in the GUI or in `bleachbit.ini`, and the directories cannot be changed on the command line.

I liked Thomas's idea, so today I committed a change for future verions that works like this.

```
bleachbit --wipe-free-space /dev/shm /tmp /home/username
```

Update: [BleachBit version 2.1](https://www.bleachbit.org/news/bleachbit-21-beta) is published, and it has the new command line option